# Extracting PDB signature from DLL file

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, portable-executable, pdb-files

I have to extract PDB signature from both *.pdb* and *.dll* file.

That's the code I use to extract it from .pdb file. Unfortunately I haven't found similiar way of extracting it from a DLL.

```
        public static string GetPdbSignature(string pdbFilePath)
        {
            using (var pdbFileStream = File.OpenRead(pdbFilePath))
            {
                var metadataProvider = MetadataReaderProvider.FromPortablePdbStream(pdbFileStream);
                var metadataReader = metadataProvider.GetMetadataReader();
                var id = new BlobContentId(metadataReader.DebugMetadataHeader.Id);

                return $"{id.Guid.ToString("N")}ffffff";
            }
        }
```

I found out that a [PeNet](https://github.com/secana/PeNet)  nuget package can be used to perform the extraction, yet I'd prefer to achieve that without installing external dependancies.

Also, I managed to find the desired data using a dotPeek ([screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxEEX.png)), but as I need to resolve the problem programatically it doesn't solve my issue either.

I'd apreciate any hint how to aproach that problem. Either by using some built in dotnet mechanism or by some smart low level byte extraction.

Comment: "but as I need to resolve the problem programatically it doesn't solve my issue either."

You could look into Reflection to do this within code. Start by looking at Assembly.Load

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find an official Microsoft's package - [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview) that contains `PEFile` class allowing to extract the exact data I need.

```cs
public static string GetDllSignature(string dllFilePath)
{
    var peFile = new PEFile.PEFile(dllFilePath);
    peFile.GetPdbSignature(out string pdbName, out Guid pdbGuid, out int pdbAge);

    return $"{pdbGuid.ToString("N")}ffffff";
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually there also is a `PEReader` class in `System.Reflection.PortableExecutable` namespace that makes the reading possible using only the system libraries. However it requires some knowledge of the portable executable format, as the `PEReader` does not provide an explicit, user-friendly method for extracting the signature, instead it just allows getting all kind of data that the PE file contains.

```cs
public static string GetDllSignatureV2(string dllFilePath)
{
    using (var pdbStream = File.OpenRead(pdbPath))
    using (var peReader = new PEReader(pdbStream))
    {
        var debugDirectory = peReader.ReadDebugDirectory().First(entry => entry.Type == DebugDirectoryEntryType.CodeView);
        var codeViewData = peReader.ReadCodeViewDebugDirectoryData(debugDirectory);

        return $"{codeViewData.Guid.ToString("N").Replace("-", string.Empty)}FFFFFFFF".ToUpper();
    }
}
```